# Azure Log analytics - availability of a service

Tags: windows, azure, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to visualize the availability of a windows service by using the System event log of a machine, which is stored into Azure Log analytics. When the service is running, I consider it as a 1 and when it is stopped, I consider it as a 0, so that I can graph it out

```
| where EventLog == "System" and Source == "Service Control Manager" and EventID == 7036 and Computer =="COMPNAME" 
| parse kind=relaxed EventData with * '<Data Name="param1">' Windows_Service_Name '</Data><Data Name="param2">' Windows_Service_State '</Data>' * 
| where Windows_Service_Name == "Svc_Name" 
| extend status = iif(Windows_Service_State == "running", "1", "0")
| summarize min(status) by bin(TimeGenerated , 1m)
| order by TimeGenerated, min_status desc
```

However, I am not getting any charts by selecting the charts on Azure Log analytics window. How can I produce a graph of availabilty using this query ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

So there is two issues in this approach, the first is the actual syntax causing your issue. You are treating the status as strings and not numbers. If you remove the quotation marks hugging the numbers the chart will work.

The second part is that these logs are event based, which means that it will just log 1 event when its stopped and 1 event when its started. So looking at a specific time is impossible. You will in your graph just see last event change and after the retention time for the log passes and there has been no changes there will be no events at all.

```
Event
| where EventLog == "System" and Source == "Service Control Manager" and EventID == 7036 and Computer =="COMPNAME" 
| parse kind=relaxed EventData with * '<Data Name="param1">' Windows_Service_Name '</Data><Data Name="param2">' Windows_Service_State '</Data>' * 
| where Windows_Service_Name == "Svc_Name" 
| extend status = iif(Windows_Service_State == "running", 1, 0)
| summarize min(status) by bin(TimeGenerated , 1m)
| order by TimeGenerated, min_status desc
```